# Windows Diskpart: How to select disk based on LUN ID

Tags: windows-server-2008, partition, disk-volume, diskpart

I have multiple LUNs attached to my Windows 2008 server from a SAN storage controller. Each LUN has a unique ID. However, it has no correlation to the disk number in the Windows. For example in the `DiskPart` utility I can see disk 1 has this property :

```
DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> detail disk

COMPELNT Compellent Vol SCSI Disk Device
Disk ID: 8052CB5B
Type   : FIBRE
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 11
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     W                RAW    Stripe      1499 GB  Healthy
```

I was wondering if there is anyway to `select disk` with its LUN ID. In other words, I am looking optimally to replace

```
select disk 1
```

with something like this

```
select disk = LUN(11)
```

However, this type of disk specification (`LUN(11)`) is not valid. What is a correct disk specification in this case ?

Comment: this page might be helpful but not sure exactly: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851589%28v=ws.10%29.aspx